# FB is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've a problem with FB JS SDK.

I'm trying to do a request to get the fan_count of a facebook page node.

Here is my code from my html file into the body :

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'your-app-id',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And when I'm using this on my js app, I use it :

```
init();

function init() {
  var id_fb  = "l214.animaux";
  while (true) {
    console.log("je suis ici");
    FB.api(
      '/' + id_fb +  '/',
      'GET',
      {"fields":"fan_count"},
      function(response) {
        alert(response.fan_count);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

But the error is that FB is not defined. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should `init` as callback URI or make sue FB is first loaded, than your init.

Comment: So I have to call `init` function at the end of `fbAsyncInit` function? It seems doesn't work for me :)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184163/javascript-my-fbasyncinit-method-never-gets-called

Comment: You also can't do an infinite loop like this in Javascript and expect ajax calls to work inside of it.  That will never work.

Comment: OK thanks, I will look it. @jfriend00 you have right, I will change that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This would be correct, you need to use FB after the JS SDK is initialized. That being said, you definitely don´t want to call FB.api in an infinite loop, so i removed that part:

```
<script>
    function init() {
        FB.api(
          '/l214.animaux',
          {"fields":"fan_count"},
          function(response) {
            alert(response.fan_count);
          }
        );
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'your-app-id',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
      });

      init();
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Make sure you run this from an actual server, don´t just open your HTML files in a browser without at least a local server.

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I've not this error of FB is not defined. But, init function is never called. I past your code and just add a console.log in init function at the begining and the web browser console stays blank

Comment: i guess the js sdk does not get loaded. are you trying this with an actual webserver, or did you just open the html file in the browser locally?

Comment: I open it locally with the html file

Comment: well...of course that does not work. try with a real server (either on localhost or on a real one). you can also add "https" to the sdk source, but i would not recommend that. developers use localhost to develop nowadays, just opening a html file in the browser is not how it is done anymore.

Comment: Yeah, this fixed it ! I've added https

Comment: I will implement a localhost server tomorrow

Comment: FB should document it. Thank a lot @luschn

Answer (score 16):

I got this error because I write the init code in an independent js file, so, of course `FB` is not defined, because it should be `window.FB`.

my code:

```
class FacebookUtil {

  static init() {
    // comes from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart
    // notice FB should be window.FB
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      window.FB.init({
        appId            : '...',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v2.10'
      });
      window.FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }

  static login() {
    window.FB.login(...)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's in react that you are dealing with here is my solution code. And you must deactivate script blocking settings ( in brave browser I saw it's blocking and was reason for that issue)

```
    



import React from "react";

export const FacebookButton = ()=>{
    const handleClick=()=>{
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
            //  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
              //  console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
             });
            } else {
            //  console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });
    }
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            window.FB.init({
                appId      : '380427166785990',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v11.0'
              });
            window.FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
          };
      
          (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        
    },[])
    
    return(
        <button  onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>    )
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>






import React from "react";

export const FacebookButton = ()=>{
    const handleClick=()=>{
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
            //  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
              //  console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
             });
            } else {
            //  console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });
    }
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            window.FB.init({
                appId      : '0500550055050',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v11.0'
              });
            window.FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
          };
      
          (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        
    },[])
    
    return(
        <button  onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>    )
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```