# How to wait for Facebook SDK load in Vue.js Single-File Component

Tags: javascript, facebook, vue.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is my first time to play with [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) but I need to use [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/) for [login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/).

Many documents [emphasize](https://github.com/phanan/vue-facebook-signin-button#usage) that the Facebook SDK must first be loaded asynchronously.

I know there are a couple of Q&As on this topic at StackOverflow, but my case differs.

1. [Using the `created` method while creating a new Vue instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39546590/1479078)
   I cannot use this option because I'm using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) and only [one component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) will use Facebook SDK for login.
2. [Using `nuxt.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43665115/1479078)
   I don't know much about Vue.js yet. Trying [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) seems like opening up a whole new can of worms.

Is there any example of loading Facebook SDK asynchronously in a Vue.js single-file component?

Answer (score 2):

After doing the following you can call any of the SDK functions, like the login one, like this: `Vue.FB.login()`. Initialize the SDK before you call the Vue constructor. In `lib/FacebookSdk.js`:

```
const initFbSdk = (Vue, facebookClientId) => {
  window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
    FB.init({
      appId: facebookClientId,
      autoLogAppEvents: true,
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v3.2',
    });
    Vue.FB = FB;
  };
};
```

And in `main.js`:

```
import { initFbSdk } from './lib/FacebookSdk';

// ...

initFbSdk(Vue, process.env.VUE_APP_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Use it in your components or anywhere else like

```
import Vue from 'vue';

// ...

Vue.FB.login(resp => {
    // ...
});
```