# How to check login state of authentified user after page refresh using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I managed to develop the login/logout using the facebook js sdk.

After login, I am able to get the email of the user.

I am having trouble when I try to get the information for a authentified user, after I refresh the entire page.

Somehow, the FB object is not there anymore.

I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined

How can I init the FB object ?

ps: I have already read and coded the solution from:

[FB is not defined javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956374/fb-is-not-defined-javascript)

but it does not work.

In that example, /me is replaced with /l214.animaux

I don't know the user profile id.

My code is divided in 2 php files:

index.php:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-scope="public_profile,email" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```

and facebook_login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <?php
        $title = Yii::app()->name;
        ?>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    </head>

    <body class="inner-page page-produse">

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>

            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id))
                    return;
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1813020315643394";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

            function api_call_get_info_about_the_logged_in_user() {

                console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information.... ');

                FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email'}, function (response) {

                    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.email);

                });

            }

            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '1813020315643394',
                    xfbml: true,
                    version: 'v2.8'
                });

                api_call_get_info_about_the_logged_in_user();
            };

            function checkLoginState() {
                FB.getLoginStatus(
                        function (response) {
                            console.log('facebook get login status');
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response.status === 'connected') {

// Logged into your app and Facebook.

                                api_call_get_info_about_the_logged_in_user();

                            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

// The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.

                            } else {

// The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if

// they are logged into this app or not.

                            }
                        }
                );
            }

        </script>

        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="site-wrapper">

                <?php
                echo $content;
                ?>

                <div class="site-wrapper-overlay"></div>

            </div> <!-- .site-wrapper -->

        </div> <!-- .wrapper -->

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts, I tried to call the checkLoginState function and it works.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '1813020315643394',
                    xfbml: true,
                    version: 'v2.8'
                });

                //api_call_get_info_about_the_logged_in_user();
                checkLoginState();
            };
```