# Facebook marketing api insights can be used in graph api explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do you see the Facebook marketing api insights in graph api explorer? Could I explain? 
Can you get the output as you see in this link? [Marketing Api Sample](https://www.facebookmarketingdevelopers.com/samples/adsreporting)

Comment: Graph API Explorer is just a tool to make API requests - _what_ requests you make using it, is up to you. (And if the real question here _is_ what should those requests look like - well, go read the documentation then.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a answer,I will expalin here

The Following Links are very usefull For this question

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/fields/v2.10
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-keyword-stats
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.10
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/fields/v2.10
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/tracking-specs/v2.10

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v2.10
```

[FB is not defined javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956374/fb-is-not-defined-javascript)

Go to 
https://developer.facebook.com and Create App and Left side nav bar to create marketing api and manage this are above tools. Any doubts comments here..

Answer (score 0):

base url can be like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/adaccounts?fields=ads,campaigns,adsets
```

you can expand any fields with subfields

if you want insights of ads you can replace ads with

```
ads{insights{reach,impressions,frequency, unique_clicks, actions, spend, cpc}}
```

and so on....