# error FB.login() called before FB.init() in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

```html
<html ng-app="faceBoookLogin">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fbController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.12'
      });
    };

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
<body ng-controller="fbController">
    <button type="button" ng-click="FBLogin()">
      Login With Facebook
     </button> 
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("faceBoookLogin", []);
app.controller("fbController", ['$scope', function($scope){
 
//call FBLogin for login with fb
$scope.FBLogin = function(){
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
    } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
  });
}

}]);
```

Hello to all,
I have implement the functionality of the login with facebook js but i got above error.I have included all.js once time but still I am getting this error "FB.login() called before calling FB.init()" when I click the login button tell m anyone how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: My fbAsyncInit() method never gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184163/javascript-my-fbasyncinit-method-never-gets-called)

Comment: Who is invoking `window.fbAsyncInit`? You are defining a function BUT nobody is calling it before going into the FBLogin. Is it?

Comment: @FDavidov sir,window.fbAsyncInit is called after the page load but FBLogin function is call after click the button

Comment: Are you asking or saying? (your **?** sign)

Comment: sir  i m saying, window.fbAsyncInit is call only once time.

Comment: Check that your app_id is set to the right one. If it's the wrong one, FB.init errors _silently_.

Comment: Sir right now i have no app_id ?

Comment: sir why we need app-id for remove this errror?